# Find Largest Prime Factor - Complexity of Code

Tags: c++, c, prime-factoring

I tried a code on a coding website to find the largest prime factor of a number and it's exceeding the time limit for the last test case where probably they are using a large prime number. Can you please help me to reduce the complexity of the following code?

```
int main()
{
    long n;
    long int lar, fact;
    long int sqroot;
    int flag;

    cin >> n;
    lar=2, fact=2;
    sqroot = sqrt(n);
    flag = 0;
    while(n>1)
    {
        if((fact > sqroot) && (flag == 0))         //Checking only upto Square Root
        {
            cout << n << endl;
            break;
        }
        if(n%fact == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            lar = fact;
            while(n%fact == 0)
                n = n/fact;
        }
        fact++;
    }
    if(flag == 1)         //Don't display if loop fact reached squareroot value
        cout << lar << endl;
}
```

Here I've also taken care of the loop checking till Square Root value. Still, how can I reduce its complexity further?

Comment: It also does not make much logical sense. I suggest first picking a programming language, then reviewing the structure of the code, including tracing and/or paper and pencil checking of behavior for some small values of `n`.

Comment: Look at this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90492/euler-3-largest-prime-factor

Comment: @Bhavuk Mathur. The below link is a solution I've found, if you add the Scott Hunter's suggestion in his answer, this solution might have a good behaviour! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90492/euler-3-largest-prime-factor/90736#90736

Comment: After `while(n%fact == 0) n = n/fact;`, re-calc the limit `sqroot = sqrt(n);`

Comment: @SergioFormiggini, i'll try that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed things up (if not reduce the complexity) by supplying a hard-coded list of the first N primes to use for the initial values of `fact`, since using composite values of `fact` are a waste of time.  After that, avoid the obviously composite values of `fact` (like even numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the number of tests by skipping even numbers larger than 2, and stopping sooner if you have found smaller factors.  Here is a simpler and faster version:

```
int main() {
    unsigned long long n, lar, fact, sqroot;

    cin >> n;
    lar = 0;
    while (n && n % 2 == 0) {
        lar = 2;
        n /= 2;
    }
    fact = 3;
    sqroot = sqrt(n);
    while (fact <= sqroot) {
        if (n % fact == 0) {
            lar = fact;
            do { n /= fact; } while (n % fact == 0);
            sqroot = sqrt(n);
        }
        fact += 2;
    }
    if (lar < n)
        lar = n;
    cout << lar << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure how large the input numbers may become, using the larger type `unsigned long long` for these computations will get you farther than `long`.  Using a precomputed array of primes would help further, but not by a large factor.

Answer (score 1):

The better result I've obtained is using the function below (`lpf5()`). It's based on the `primality()` function (below) that uses the formulas 6k+1, 6k-1 to individuate prime numbers. All prime numbers >= 5 may be expressed in one of the forms `p=k*6+1` or `p=k*6-1` with k>0 (but not all the numbers having such a forms are primes). Developing these formulas we can see a sequence like the following:

```
k=1 5,7
k=2 11,13
k=3 17,19
k=4 23,25*
k=5 29,31
.
.
.
k=10 59,61
k=11 65*,67
k=12 71,73
...

5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,...,59,61,65,67,71,73,...
```

We observe that the difference between the terms is alternatively 2 and 4. Such a results may be obtained also using simple math. Is obvious that the difference between k*6+1 and k*6-1 is 2. It's simple to note that the difference between k*6+1 and (k+1)*6-1 is 4.

The function `primality(x)` returns x when x is prime (or 0 - take care) and the first divisor occurs when x is not prime.

I think you may obtain a better result inlining the `primality()` function inside the `lpf5()` function.

I've also tried to insert a table with some primes (from 1 to 383 - the primes in the first 128 results of the indicated formulas) inside the primality function, but the speed difference is unappreciable.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef  long long unsigned int uint64;
uint64 lpf5(uint64 x);
uint64 primality(uint64 x);

uint64 lpf5(uint64 x)
{
    uint64 x_=x;

    while ( (x_=primality(x))!=x)
        x=x/x_;

    return x;
}

uint64 primality(uint64 x)
{
    uint64 div=7,f=2,q;

    if (x<4 || x==5)
        return x;

    if (!(x&1))
        return 2;

    if (!(x%3))
        return 3;

    if (!(x%5))
        return 5;

    q=sqrt(x);
    while(div<=q) {
        if (!(x%div)) {
            return div;
        }
        f=6-f;
        div+=f;
    }

    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    uint64 x,k;

    do {
        printf("Input long int: ");
        if (scanf("%llu",&x)<1)
            break;

        printf("Largest Prime Factor: %llu\n",lpf5(x));
    } while(x!=0);

    return 0;
}
```